# After Conversion from Xlsx to csv file, Seconds in Date filed is not displaying properly using Python

Tags: python, excel, date, csv, xlsx

While using the python script to convert an xlsx file into csv files, I'm facing the issue where the seconds in a date fields are displaying wrong. For example I have a cell value as "2/23/2017 2:05:32 PM", but after conversion the value is something like this "2/23/2017 2:05:31 PM". Please find the attached Python, Unix Shell scripts used for this conversion and please help me.

***********Unix  Shell Script : xlsx2csv.sh****************

```
./xlsx2csv.py -d "," -f "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" -i -s 1 $sheet1.csv
./xlsx2csv.py -d "," -f "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" -i -s 2 $sheet2.csv
./xlsx2csv.py -d "," -f "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" -i -s 3 $sheet3.csv
```

**********Python Script xlsx2csv.py**********

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rv5e5una3b15zqm/xlsx2csv.py?dl=0

Comment: Also provide csv file link

Comment: Please find  the source xlsx file from the below location https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gk2w6taqxjvl6v/Source%20%281%29.xls?dl=0